# Azure Media Services Streaming Endpoint Is useful for MP4 videos streaming speed?

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, azure-media-services

We are using Azure Media Services to play the MP4 videos.

In Azure Media Services there is a option to change the Streaming endpoints and it's units ( 1 unit = 200 mbps)

In my MP4 videos case if I increase my streaming endpoint units there will be any improvement in performance/ speed? or streaming is only applicable for MPEG-DASH/ HLS (.ism) videos only

Currently we didn't put any streaming endpoint units but it is playing instantly using Azure Media Player with out any delay in desktop.

But when it comes to Mobile Device(Android Samsung S4 5.0.1) same Azure Media Player in chrome browser taking 10 sec or more delay, to overcome this finally I used exoplayer to play the video it is also taking 6 to 7 seconds very first time but if we play same video second time it is taking max of 3 seconds delay.

I don't want that delay also and it should come down to 1 or 2 seconds max either first time or any time.

Is Streaming Endpoints really useful in this case or what should be the alternative ways to achieve streaming speed in mobile device.

if you guys suggest me best instant play video player for Xamarin Android also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If current your video is Multi-bitrate Mp4 and you have no streaming reserved unit, I guess you are getting a SAS URL for your video. That's progressive download and essentially the video is getting downloaded like a file from storage directly and our streaming service is just passing it through. However, if you purchase one reserved unit, you are actually adaptive streaming the video in streaming format such as Smooth Streaming, HLS and MPEG-DASH. The player will pull the right bitrates according to your current bandwidth and device CPU. Therefore, it will minimize the buffering. Here are  of my blogs to explain the concept:

- http://mingfeiy.com/progressive-download-video-streaming
- http://mingfeiy.com/traditional-streaming-video-streaming
- http://mingfeiy.com/adaptive-streaming-video-streaming

Therefore, by increasing the reserved unit more than 1 doesn't help on the loading if you don't hit the bandwidth limit. However, turning reserved unit from 0 to 1 does fundamentally improve the performance.

Comment: Thank you @Mingfei Yan for your clarification. I want to know few more thing form you like, 1. If I purchase one reserved streaming unit my current MP4 SAS URL will auto change to smooth streaming or I need to republish that. 2. In Azure portal we have option to Process uploaded video, if I want to smooth stream my uploaded MP4 video I should also do that? 3. After purchase of one streaming Unit, if I create locator using OnDemand then it will give me OnDemand URL or it will start a job to process my video and then return the URL?

Comment: I have one more concern like we are uploading video from client mobile it self to Azure Media Services using Rest API(Xamarin Android) by following your Rest API sample project. in GenerateRequestAndGetResponse method you guys used JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader as we are using PCL so no way it supporting us, can you guys re-write that few lines and make support PCL also?

Comment: You will need to generate a OnDemandOrigin URL to your MP4 (assume that's H.264 and there is a .ism in the folder), if not, you can re-encode your file with H.264 multi-bitrate profile with our encoder. You will get the locator right away and it will start working. You dont need to wait for the URL to be returned.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Xamarin SDK you mentioned. Who did that project?

Comment: sorry for not providing more information related to Rest API. This API written by Microsoft Azure team itself (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/tree/dev/samples/MediaServicesRESTSample). We used this Rest API in our PCL library project. But PCL not supporting JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader Method written in above mentioned Rest API in Program.cs file. Because of PCL limitation I am not able to use that Rest API sample written by your Azure guys in my project. For that I am asking some one from your side to re-write that sample rest API project to support PCL also